# Server 2008 R2 - Boot disk RAID 1 - migrate to larger disk

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid, diskpart

My group inherited several **2008 R2 servers** with single 70GB **RAID 1** boot/system disks.

**No other disks** in the servers.

**We need larger boot / system disk**.

Plan is :

- to replace one disk with new 500 GB drive
- wait for resync
- replace other smaller disk with 2nd 500 GB drive
- wait for resysnc

Now I should have **500 GB RAID 1** with original **70 GB partition**

Then I would like to **extend the 70 GB partition** to 200 GB and **add D: drive partition** with remaining 300 GB

Can the above be done using Windows **Disk Management** and / or Windows **DiskPart** ?

Comment: Are these software RAIDs or is there a hardware RAID controller in the machines?

Comment: HARDWARE Raid - embedded RAID controllers - hot plug 2.5" SAS drives

Comment: Which HW RAID card? Both brand and specific model please. Did the card come with management software? Is that software installed?

Comment: Server: Dell R710, ..

RAID Controller: PERC6i, ..

Management software:  Dell OpenManage

Comment: When extending partition with Windows Disk Management be careful as I did similar thing and got into the trouble. You can see my question.

Answer (score 2):

You have the general idea for how to do this. What you want to do this this:

1. Take a full backup. Every time you break redundancy, you risk a disaster. Better safe than sorry.
2. Replace one 73GB disk with a 500GB disk. Wait for a rebuild to complete.
3. Replace the other 73GB disk with the other 500GB disk. Wait for the rebuild to complete.
4. Use Dell OpenManage Server Administrator to extend the size of the physical RAID 1 volume on the disk from 73GB to 500GB. I believe you're looking for the "reconfigure" option, but consult the manual if you're unsure.
5. Open `diskmgmt.msc` or `diskpart.exe`, your choice, and scan for changes. The additional 400ish GB of empty space should show up. Extend your existing volume to 200GB and create a new partition for the rest.

Assuming everything goes smoothly, you can do this online and with no downtime.